# Migrating On From HTML --> JavaScript --> CSS -->?

Tags: javascript, html, css

We have a program that is developed via a combination of HTML, JavaScript, CSS.  It works fine, but there are a lot of stand-alone files and we're thinking of moving on to a new development platform.

What are some selling points to move over to VS 2010, .NET, C# .NET, JScript ?

Thanks

Comment: There are more options to consider than just .NET technologies

Answer (score 1):

Well, a lot of files should not be the only reason you want to move :)

.NET and other server technologies provide you ability to use server-side computing and this gives you a lot of advantages from only client-side access.

You would be able to read/write to disc, use databases to store you data and configuration, you could use smarter technologies to make templates for you HTML files and CSS (this might limit the number of files :) ).

The languages themselves provide richer API, so you could achieve more.

Comment: We don't really have need for a database on this particular project.  Could you elaborate on:  (1) smarter technologies to make templates for you HTML files and CSS (this might limit the number of files and (2) richer API ?  Thanks.

Comment: I can elaborate, but I think you should describe your needs firs - what are the limitations you have and what is not convenient in the system you are using.